# Кастомизация radiobutton без использования изображений

Tags: java, android

В нете куча информации о том, как кастомизировать `RadioButton` путем указания в селекторе ресурс изображения. Можно ли использовать вместо изображения drawable xml ресурс, в котором с помощью shape будет описан `RadioButton`? почему-то не работает.

Comment: при использовании такого подхода, радиобатн не видно вообще

Comment: Ещё на элементы можно накладывать цветовые фильтры. Незначительная, но всё же - кастомизация

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь вам это поможет. Простой пример.

Создайте файл red_ring.xml.
Путь файла для создания: res/drawable/red_ring.xml

Вставьте в файл этот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
 android:shape="ring"
 android:thickness="10dp"
 android:useLevel="false" >

 <solid android:color="#FF0000" />

 <size
  android:height="30dp"
  android:width="30dp" />

</shape>
```

По тому же пути создайте 2-ой файл blue_ring.xml . 
Код для вставки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
 android:shape="ring"
 android:thickness="5dp"
 android:useLevel="false" >

 <solid android:color="#0000FF" />

 <size
  android:height="20dp"
  android:width="20dp" />

 </shape>
```

Отрисовываем несколько слоев для выбранного элемента:

Файл res/drawable/layer.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_ring"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_ring"/>
  </layer-list>
```

Также создаем - res/drawable/selector_radio.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/layer"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue_ring"/>
</selector>
```

И пример того как все это добавить в RadioButton

```
<RelativeLayout               
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center" >

  <RadioButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/selector_radio"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:text="Radio 1" />

  <RadioButton
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:button="@drawable/selector_radio"
    android:paddingLeft="30dp"
    android:text="Radio 2" />
  </RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```